# how do i get a dict as dict back from csv fille

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

hello i want to write a dictionary in my csv file and then get it as dictonary back when i read it i searched in some python forums and also saw this "csv dictreader " but i dont know properly how to use it so i ask here.
I imagined it like this but this dont work

```
x = open('file','w')
a = {}
a['hi'] = 'yes'
x.write(str(a))
x.close
x = open('file','r')
a = x.read()
```

and then i want to get it back as dict

```
print(a['hi])
```

i do that to test it but i just get a string and i need to write it as a string becaus i cant write dicts in csv files do you have any solution that help me with my problem? 
THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module.

In your case the usage would be:

```
# Write the dict
pickle.dump(a, open("file", "wb"))

# Read the dict
a = pickle.load(open("file", "rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution will be to write the file in the json fromat insted of the csv format. Use **json.dumps** to convert the datastructure (e.g. dict of list with integer) to the json representation (string). Then write it to a file. The content read from the file (string with the json representation) can be convert to the datastructure using **json.loads**.